# How to create a string to only output 6 characters that can only start with CX

Tags: python

I have a project where i have to write a code that does the following below. I was able to figure out the characters string, but im struggling with it must begin with CX and exclude 0 and 1. Below is what i have so far.

-Exactly six characters long
-Begins with "CX"
-Does not contain the digits 0 or 1

from random import randint

## Product Checks

## User input Product number

`enter code here`productnum = input("Input the product number:")

`enter code here`n = len(productnum)
`enter code here`x = productnum [0]
`enter code here`if n != 6:
`enter code here`print("The product number must be 6 characters")

Answer (score 0):

```
productnum = input("Input the product number:")

while len(productnum) != 6 or "0" in productnum or "1" in productnum or not productnum.startswith("CX"):
    print("input error, please try again!")
    productnum = input("Input the product number:")
print("your number: ", productnum)
```

Comment: Wow. Thank you! We haven't went over while yet. This was very helpful.